# The conditional mean $E[W_5|X(t)=3]$ of Poisson process

Tags: probability, statistics, stochastic-processes, proof-explanation, poisson-process

Customers arrive at a service facility according to a Poisson process of rate $\lambda$ customers/hour. Let $X(t)$ be the number of customers that have arrived up to time $t$. Let $W_1,W_2,...$ be the successive arrival times of the customers. Determine the conditional mean $E[W_5|X(t)=3]$

Solution:

First we compute the distribution function of $W_5|X(t)=3$, using the cumulative distribution function.

Let $t>u$. Then, we want to compute $P(W_5\ge u|X(t)=3)$ which is the probability of having 5 customers from time $t$ until time $u$.

But this is equivalent to this $P(X(u)\ge 2|X(t)=3)$ probability $\color{fuchsia}{...(1)}$

So,$P(W_5\ge u|X(t)=3)=P(X(u)\ge 2|X(t)=3)=P[(X(u)-X(t))\ge 2]=1- P[(X(u)-X(t))< 2]=1- P[(X(u)-X(t))= 0]-P[(X(u)-X(t))=1]=1-e^{-\lambda (u-t)}-\lambda e^{\lambda (u-t)}$.

So the distribution function is $(u-t)\lambda ^2 e^{-(u-t)\lambda} =f_w(u)$.

Therefore $E[W_5|X(t)=3]=\int_t^{\infty}uf_w(u)du$.

I don't understand the equivalence $\color{fuchsia}{(1)}$, why $P(W_5\ge u|X(t)=3)=P(X(u)\ge 2|X(t)=3)$ ??

Can somebody explain to me this step?

Thanks.

Comment: It shouldn't be. $X(t)$ represents number of customers arrived in time $[0,t]$ and if $u$ represents the time (from $W_5 \geq u$) then $X(t) \geq u$ does not make any sense.

Comment: It should be $P(W_5\geq u | X(t) = 3) = P(X(u) \geq 5 | X(t) = 3)$. And the 
 equations follows as you wrote. Of course, $u \geq t$ otherwise the probability is $0$.

Comment: yeah of course, my mistake. I fixed it @expiTTp1z0

Comment: @expiTTp1z0 I think it should be 2 instead of 5

Comment: Again it is incorrect. Check my second comment.

Comment: According to your definition of $X(t)$ which is the number of customers arrived till time $t$, $P(X(u) \geq 2 | X(t) = 3) = 1$ for $u \geq t$, because till time $u$, $3$ customers would have already arrived.

Comment: @expiTTp1z0 You're right :D